# SwiftUI - How to access data in a list

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I would like to change a value in a list. Thats what I have:

```
struct ExpenseItem {
    let value : String
    let currency : String
    let shopName : String
    let code : String
}

final class Expenses: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [ExpenseItem]()
}
```

How can I access now this data? It doesnt work by the following method. It says

> Value of type '[ExpenseItem]' has no member 'value'

```
@EnvironmentObject var expenses: Expenses
@State private var value = ""

var body: some View {
        Form() {
            Section(header: Text("Wert")) {
                TextField(self.expenses.items.value, text: $value)
```

Comment: It is not very clear what are you going to achieve... `TextField` first argument is actually a placeholder... your `items` is just an array, so indeed `array` does not have value... you need some item of array either by index, or first, last, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ForEach` to iterate over all `items`:

```swift
@EnvironmentObject var expenses: Expenses

var body: some View {
    Form() {
        Section(header: Text("Wert")) {
            ForEach(0 ..< self.expenses.items.count) { i in
                TextField(self.expenses.items[i].value, text: self.$expenses.items[i].value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```